# How to understand which device is which in the /dev directory

Tags: devices

I am new in UNIX/Linux programming. I need a clear reference of each file in `/dev` directory and which file refers to which devices. I have read many posts but its not only confusing but also sharing very little data. Is there any online documentation or any os internal file that can give clear information about those device files?

For example

> /proc/bus/input/devices

this file give some information about all input devices .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /dev directory in UNIX is generally a folder that contains device files, and is how the O/S contacts the components on the system. Some of these are going to be actual devices, like a hard disk, network card, usb port, keyboard, or mouse. Some are "virtual" devices that are used for special purposes, such as sending output to /dev/null file, or a pseudo random number generator (/dev/random).

If you have the "lshw" package installed, that will list the actual hardware info, along with some device names. There is also lspci, lsmem, lscpu, lsusb, and probably a few others to help identify components on the system.

But to my knowledge, there is no single document or help file that will explain what all the files in /dev directory are used for. In general, I'd suggest if there are any you are curious about, just do a browser search for `Ubuntu /dev/{device-filename}` and odds are good someone has a description of the file's purpose.

Comment: correction - `/dev/random` is a pseudorandom bytes generator - not an RNG.

Comment: I am very new in linux . Thanks, I was really looking `lshw` like command .

Comment: Thanks Thomas, yes. Thanks for that correction, my gaming and DnD background showing through.... The /dev/random can be used to generate random bytes, not a number. It lets you populate a file (for example) with something resembling real binary data, instead of all zeroes or blank space.